# Strengthening an inequality of exponential series

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, factorial, products, symmetric-polynomials

A question posits that, show:
$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\ldots(1+x_n)\\ \leq 1+\dfrac{S}{1!}+\dfrac{S^2}{2!}+\ldots\dfrac{S^n}{n!}$$
Where $S=\sum x_i$, $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$

Now, the RHS looked like the exponential series so I naturally thought to use the inequality that:
$$e^x\geq1+x$$

However, this proves the inequality for the infinite series, whenever it converges.
How can we prove this for just upto n terms?

Comment: Consider $x_1=100002$, $x_2=-100000$,  $x_3=-2$. Then the sum is zero....

Comment: The $x_i$ should be non-negative, right?

Answer (score 2):

I propose my solution as well. Noticing that:

$f(x): x \rightarrow log(1+x)$

is convex on $[0,+\infty]$, we have, applying convexity inequality on $(x_1,...,x_n)$ with equal weights:

$\prod_i (1+x_i) \le (1+\frac{S}{n})^n$

Now it is easy to see that:

$(1+\frac{S}{n})^n=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} \frac{S^i}{n^i}\le 1+...+S^n/n!$.

just by comparing the coefficients of the monomials term by term. Combining the previous two inequalities we have an alternative derivation with respect to the ones proposed, maybe more elementary.

Answer (score 0):

The statement holds for non-negative $x_i$, otherwise it is false: see the comments. So the proof uses the necessary extra condition. In fact, we may assume that all the $x_i$ are positive, as zeros do not make a difference in either of the two sides.

Let $0\leq k\leq n$. We denote by $m_k$ the sum of all degree $k$ monomials obtained by expanding the product $(1+x_1)\cdots (1+x_n)$. 
Given $n\geq i_1\geq i_2\geq \cdots \geq i_n\geq 0$ such that $i_1+\cdots +i_n=k$, the average of the monomials $x_{\sigma(1)}^{i_1}x_{\sigma(2)}^{i_2} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{i_n}$ on all $n!$ permutations $\sigma$ is less than the special average of the sum of monomials for the sequence $i_1=1, i_2=1, \ldots, i_k=1, i_{k+1}=0, \ldots, i_n=0$. 
This is Muirhead's inequality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality), provided that all the $x_i$ are positive. 
The special average is $\frac{m_k}{\binom{n}{k}}$.

Hence, by expanding $S^k= (x_1+\cdots +x_n)^k$ we obtain $n^k$ monomials which in average are at least $\frac{m_k}{\binom{n}{k}}$ (as it is the weighted average of some averages that are all greater than or equal to $\frac{m_k}{\binom{n}{k}}$). 
So $\frac{S^k}{n^k}\geq \frac{m_k}{\binom{n}{k}}\geq \frac{m_k}{n^k/k!}$, and consequently, $m_k\leq \frac{S^k}{k!}$.

Your problem follows easily by adding up these estimations for all $0\leq k\leq n$:

$$(1+x_1)\cdots (1+x_n)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} m_k\leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{S^k}{n^k}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's true for non-negative variables.

Indeed,   for $n\geq k\geq l\geq1$  by Maclaurin we obtain: $$\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}...x_{i_k}}{\binom{n}{k}}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\leq\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_l\leq n}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}...x_{i_l}}{\binom{n}{l}}\right)^{\frac{1}{l}},$$
which gives
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)=1+S+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j+...+\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leq$$
$$\leq1+S+\frac{\binom{n}{2}S^2}{n^2}+\frac{\binom{n}{3}S^3}{n^3}+...+\frac{S^n}{n^n}\leq$$
$$\leq1+S+\frac{S^2}{2!}+\frac{S^3}{3!}+...+\frac{S^n}{n!}.$$
I used that
$$\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{n^kk!}\leq\frac{1}{k!}.$$